# Logging into music partners site

Tags: sonos

### UPDATE:
Sonos was doing a major update on their developer site, which kept them from adding new users for several weeks. As of 10-Jul-23 it is working again.

How do we get credentials for the sonos labs / developer site?

We get the following page:

*musicpartners.sonos.com (Sonos Labs)

Sonos is currently updating our platform tools to ensure our partners can integrate seamlessly with our systems. As part of this effort, we have temporarily added an additional authentication layer to Sonos Labs to improve security.

If you are an existing partner, we have emailed you with your authentication credentials.  If you are new to Sonos Labs and would like to request access, please email us at sonoslabs@sonos.com

To continue, please enter your additional new credentials on the following page:*

And that's were I'm getting either Server Error 500 or a "Problem Logging In ... We can’t log you in because of an authentication error."

I've tried emailing SonosLabs@sonos.com asking for our account credentials to be approved, but don't get an answer.

Any suggestion on who I can contact to fix this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried https://integration.sonos.com/users/sign_up ? Got there from developer.sonos.com / Sign-in / Create account. Note that there are a lot of 404s since the site update a few weeks ago.

Comment: This is now working, Sonos was in the middle of re-doing their developer/partner site and authentication was not working for a few weeks.

Comment: Now the site works again maybe someone will update the content with the last year's worth of changes? A revision history would be gravy.